# Why can I not use the MAX and MIN values of f32 and f64 in a call to rand::rngs::ThreadRng::gen_range() in Rust

Tags: random, rust, range

I have a utility I've written to generate dummy data. For example, you might write:

```
giveme 12000 u32
```

... to get an array of 12000 32-bit unsigned integers.

It is possible to set a maximum and/or minimum allowed value, so you might write:

```
giveme 100 f32 --max=155.25
```

If one or the other is not given, the programme uses `type::MAX` and `type::MIN`.

With the floating point types, however, one cannot pass those values to `rand::rngs::ThreadRng::gen_range()`.

Here is my code for the f64:

```rust
fn generate_gift(gift_type: &    GiftType,
                 generator: &mut rand::rngs::ThreadRng,
                 min:            Option<f64>,
                 max:            Option<f64>) -> Gift
{
    match gift_type
    {
        ...
        GiftType::Float64 =>
        {
            let _min: f64 = min.unwrap_or(f64::MIN);
            let _max: f64 = max.unwrap_or(f64::MAX);
            let x: f64 = generator.gen_range(_min..=_max);
            Gift::Float64(x)
        },
    }
}
```

If one or both of the limits is missing for floating point, 32 or 64-bit, then I get this error:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'UniformSampler::sample_single: range overflow', /home/jack/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/rand-0.8.5/src/distributions/uniform.rs:998:1
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

It is not obvious to me at all why this error arises. Can you shed any light upon it?

Answer (score 2):

Its a limitation in `rand`.

In the source code it calculates `high - low` which is `inf` in your case, the implementation checks this and raises this error.

https://docs.rs/rand/0.8.5/src/rand/distributions/uniform.rs.html#811-814

The algorithm first calculates a random number in `[1,2)` then scales it with the length of the interval.

Answer (score 1):

It's a limitation of what it used to generate the float number, see [#1090](https://github.com/rust-random/rand/issues/1090).

> gen_range(f64::MIN..f64::MAX) results in high - low overflowing

See the [book](https://rust-random.github.io/book/intro.html)

> f64: we treat this as an approximation of the real numbers, and, by convention, restrict to the range 0 to 1 (if not otherwise specified). We will come back to the conversions used later; for now note that these produce 52-53 bits of precision (depending on which conversion is used, output will be in steps of ε or ε/2, where 1+ε is the smallest representable value greater than 1).

> For f32 and f64 the range 0.0 .. 1.0 is used (exclusive of 1.0), for two reasons: (a) this is common practice for random-number generators and (b) because for many purposes having a uniform distribution of samples (along the Real number line) is important, and this is only possible for floating-point representations by restricting the range.